# Get string representation of a TypeScript node using TypeScript Compiler API

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors

Is there a way to get a string representation of a TypeScript AST Node using the [public compiler API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API)?

I'd like to get a readable representation of computed fields, so I can, for example, refer to the computed property below as "computed property '2 + 5'"

```
{
  [ 2 + 5] () {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [ts-simple-ast](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-simple-ast) library provides access the compiler AST at runtime. There's an online viewer here: https://ts-ast-viewer.com/

Note - you will need to change the TypeScript version to @next for it to parse computed values as members. Under a ClassDefinition the property will be defined as a MethodDeclaration instance.

Comment: But I'm looking for how to get the parser errors. The ts-simple-ast library doesn't document how to do that.